# Subversion : save working copy state

Tags: svn, save, backup

Imagine we have a repository "my_repository" with theses files :

- my_repository/file01 (revision 105)
- my_repository/file02 (revision 110)
- my_repository/file03 (revision 125)
- my_repository/folder01/file01 (revision 100)
- etc...etc...

I would like to save this state. So if I do a svn update my_repository, I could backup to my previous state with all different file states easily.

Is it possible ?

Comment: In Subversion, the mixing and matching of various file revisions in a single working directory is highly discouraged. In fact, it's pretty bad practice with any version control system. If you find yourself with dozens of different revisions in your working copy, it's likely that you're not doing something in an optimal way. Why do you have all of your files in different revisions in the same working directory? Once we understand that, we might be able to recommend a better way of handling this.

Comment: Well, my website is a working copy and mysite.local is also a working copy.

When I develop a new feature, I just do a svn update on the website.

But this time, a big feature has been made during months and I continued to update new smaller features on the website copy.

So I have my working website with the schema as I described upside.

I want to "backup" this schema is case of problems on my website (angry users, choice, whatever) without making a simple copy of the root directory.

Answer (score 2):

- Forget about CVS and file-level versioning
- Welcome to Subversion World, where we operate with **GLOBAL REPOSITORY-WIDE REVISIONS**
- Use "last-change-of-file" revision as *informational* data, not *operational* data. Because you must operarate with **revision of repository** for any part of repository tree
- Every stored set of changes (*commit*) add new *revision* to *repository*, revisions forms history of changes of **repository as integral object**, each revision is frozen slice of tree

for you tree (defined part)

```
my_repository/file01 (revision 105)
my_repository/file02 (revision 110)
my_repository/file03 (revision 125)
my_repository/folder01/file01 (revision 100)
```

you'll use, remember and manipulate later with `my_repository@125` URL (common path, most recent revision) and when and if you'll want to return to exactly this state, you'll `svn up` your Working Copy for `my_repository/` to revision 125 and all objects in tree below root will appear in the exactly the same state as it was initially.

As phasetwenty wrote, you can use tags, wwhich are only text labels for easy memorization and orientation in pure digital history

**Final Note**
I **strongly recommend** that you **read and understand** SVN Book about Subversion fundamental, basic concepts, principles and ideology

Answer (score 1):

One of the core features of any version control system worth caring about is the ability to [branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.whatis.html) a revision of your project.

Also relevant is the concept of creating [tags](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.tags.html).  This might be more inline with what you want. You'll want a branch if you'd like to make separate changes to that revision.

Comment: Well, I started to create with hard svn copy command. 
The method explained in branch documentation is about "branching" on the repository, but what I want is branching on a workingcopy. 
file01 is on revision 105 in this working copy, but on the repository, modifications has been made on revision 110, 115, 125 on this file as well.
So I was thinking to copy theses files from the working copy to a folder {root_repository}/Branches/, then commit Branches, is it the right method ?

Comment: Not exactly. What I would recommend in this case is to branch the HEAD revision of the directory containing all of your files, and reverse merge each of them to the revision you've selected, then commit the changes to your branch. This has the added bonus of tracking what you've been doing in the repository.

Comment: I made a blog post about this question! http://www.chaverma.com/blog/index.php/2012/11/complex-branching-in-subversion/

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need new branch.